# Array Pagination

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this script that I'm trying to convert to pagination. Can anyone assist?

```
$valuess = json_decode(file_get_contents('data/blogs.json'));

foreach ($valuess as $data){
    $data = clone (object)array_reverse((array)$data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $values){

        if ($values->status === '1' && $values->visible === '1' && strtotime($values->date_added) <= strtotime(date('r'))){
            echo '
                <article class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 mb-4" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
                    <div class="blog-article" data-href="{{domain}}/' . strip_tags($values->slug) . '">
                        <link itemprop="image" href="{{cdn}}/uploads/' . str_replace('blog/', '', strip_tags($values->cover_image)) . '" />
                        <picture>
                            <img data-src="{{cdn}}/' . imageLoad('uploads/' . str_replace('blog/', '', strip_tags($values->cover_image)), 450, 253) . '" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" class="lazy img-fluid" alt="' . strip_tags($values->heading) . '" title="' . strip_tags($values->heading) . '" height="253" width="450" />
                        </picture>

                        <h3 itemprop="headline">' . strip_tags($values->heading) . '</h3>

                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap align-content-start mt-3">
                            <figure>
                                <img data-src="{{cdn}}/' . imageLoad('uploads/' . strip_tags($values->author->image), 45, 45) . '" class="lazy" alt="Photo of ' . strip_tags($values->author->name) . '" title="Photo of ' . strip_tags($values->author->name) . '" height="45" width="45" />
                            </figure>

                            <div class="author" itemprop="author">' . strip_tags($values->author->name) . '</div> <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="' . date('c', strtotime($values->date_added)) . '" class="date">' . date('d F Y', strtotime($values->date_added)) . '</time>
                        </div>

                        <p>' . strip_tags($values->excerpt) . '</p>

                        <a href="{{domain}}/' . strip_tags($values->slug) . '" title="Read: ' . strip_tags($values->heading) . '" itemprop="url">Continue Reading <i class="icon-right-1"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm at 80 articles now and would like each page to be 30 articles, I'll be using a query string to do this ?page=2 but for the life of me I cannot workout how to make it work. Here is what the json looks like:

```
    "blogs": {
        "1": {
            "slug": "blog\/cfsdgfdgfd",
            "cover_image": "cfsdgfdgfd.jpg",
            "author": {
                "name": "dsfdsaf",
                "image": "fdsafas",
                "email": "fdsafsa"
            },
            "heading": "fdgdfg",
            "excerpt": "sdfdsfdsaf",
            "date_added": "2019-04-25T12:21:31+10:00",
            "date_modified": "2021-12-07T14:05:12+10:00",
            "visible": "1",
            "comments": "0",
            "status": "1"
        },
        "2": {
            "slug": "blog\/hxgch",
            "cover_image": "fdghhfd.jpg",
            "author": {
                "name": "fdghf",
                "image": "zhd",
                "email": "k"jhgk
            },
            "heading": "kjhkhjg",
            "excerpt": "hgfdhfd",
            "date_added": "2019-05-09T13:31:04+10:00",
            "date_modified": "2021-12-07T11:40:49+10:00",
            "visible": "1",
            "comments": "0",
            "status": "1"
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you planning to do paginate using Javascript if PHP?

Comment: @Dula I plan on using PHP to Paginate.

Comment: ``$valuess`` contains the above json?

Comment: @Dula Yes, then $data controls each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your JSON has some small errors. It is not valid JSON.
Following is the correct JSON.

```
{
  "blogs": {
    "1": {
      "slug": "blog\/cfsdgfdgfd",
      "cover_image": "cfsdgfdgfd.jpg",
      "author": {
        "name": "dsfdsaf",
        "image": "fdsafas",
        "email": "fdsafsa"
      },
      "heading": "fdgdfg",
      "excerpt": "sdfdsfdsaf",
      "date_added": "2019-04-25T12:21:31+10:00",
      "date_modified": "2021-12-07T14:05:12+10:00",
      "visible": "1",
      "comments": "0",
      "status": "1"
    },
    "2": {
      "slug": "blog\/hxgch",
      "cover_image": "fdghhfd.jpg",
      "author": {
        "name": "fdghf",
        "image": "zhd",
        "email": "kjhgk"
      },
      "heading": "kjhkhjg",
      "excerpt": "hgfdhfd",
      "date_added": "2019-05-09T13:31:04+10:00",
      "date_modified": "2021-12-07T11:40:49+10:00",
      "visible": "1",
      "comments": "0",
      "status": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

In your code you are considering the `json_decode` values as objects but I `json_decode` it as an associate array as I think it is easier to work with.

Following is the code with pagination.

```
$fileData = file_get_contents("Path to your JSON file");
$jsonData = json_decode($fileData, true);
$itemsPerPage = 1;
$nextPage = 1; // You can access this as $currentPage =  $_GET['page'];
$counter = 0;

foreach ($jsonData['blogs'] as $jsonDatum){

    if ($jsonDatum['status'] === '1' && $jsonDatum['visible'] === '1' && strtotime($jsonDatum['date_added']) <= strtotime(date('r'))){

        $lastIndex = ($itemsPerPage * $nextPage);
        $firstIndex = (($itemsPerPage * $nextPage) - $itemsPerPage);

        if ($firstIndex <= $counter && $counter < $lastIndex) {

            // Your HTML code comes here
            // echo("<article></article>");

            // access the values using array indexes
            $cover_image = $jsonDatum['cover_image'];
            $authorName = $jsonDatum['author']['name'];

        }
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. https://www.sitecentre.com.au/blog I added pagination here, seriously, you’re a life saver!